# How to map to overload Qt slot

Tags: c++, qt, qsignalmapper

I want to overload a Qt SLOT to either react to an emitted `clicked()` `SIGNAL` from a `QPushButton` or a `stateChanged(int)` SIGNAL from a `QCheckBox` (since there is no SIGNAL that emits when the checkbox is checked only).

So these are my two SLOTs.

```
void Widget::sendCom(QString data)
{
    std::cout << "In scope of sendCom"<< std::endl;
}
void Widget::sendCom(QString data, int state)
{
    std::cout << "In scope of overloaded sendCom: " << std::endl;
}
```

With `widget->createButton(SLOT(sendCom(QString), data);` i call the following and the mapping works fine.

```
void Widget::createButton(const char *member, QString &data)
{
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    signalMapper->setMapping(button, data);
    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, member);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    ...
}


void Widget::createCheckBox(const char *member, QString &data)
{
}
```

with `widget->createCheckBox(SLOT(QString, int), data)` i want to pass in ChechBox's state to the overloaded `Widget::sendCom(QString data, int state)`as well. How has the mapping to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation `QSignalMapper` only manages parameterless signals. You could derive an new class from `QCheckBox` where you connect the `stateChanged(int)` SIGNAL to a corresponding slot in the class where you emit a `setChecked()` or a `setUnchecked()` SIGNAL which can be handled by a `QSignalMapper`.

Comment: That might be the most efficient way. I thought of identifying the sender and getting the state via `setCheckState` with a dynamic_cast

Comment: Implemented as suggested. Works like a charm.